# What are the mathematical differences between the Perceptron and the MP-Neuron?

Tags: neural-networks, perceptron

I try to understand the differences between the MP Neuron and the Perceptron. Is my understanding right that the MP Neuron mathematically only differences in the activation function. I.e. the MP Neuron only has the Threshold function as activation function and the Perceptron can have all kinds of activation function like ReLU, Softmax etc?

**MP Neuron in my understanding**

[image]

**Perceptron in my understanding**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

McCulloch-Pitts (MP) neurons only accept binary inputs, and the activation function is the binary threshold. Perceptron (not the algorithm) accepts real valued inputs, and it uses [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) as the activation.

Comment: ah intersting. And can you clarify what the difference is between binary threshold and heaviside step?

Comment: Heaviside uses 0 as threshold while binary threshold can use any $T$.